# Check if point lies inside triangle

Tags: code-golf, geometry

Your goal is to determine whether a given 2D point X lies within the area of the triangle with given vertices A,B,C.

Write a function that takes in the coordinates of the test point X and the three triangle vertices (so that's 8 coordinates total) and returns True if the point lies inside that triangle, and False if it lies outside.

Don't worry about edge cases. If the point lies on the boundary of the triangle (edge or vertex) or the triangle is actually a line segment, your code can do whatever, including crashing. Also don't worry about numerical stability or floating-point precision.

Your code must be a named function. Code snippets will not be accepted.

Fewest characters wins.

**Input:**

Eight real numbers representing coordinates. The numbers will lie in the range `(-1,1)`.

The exact input format is flexible. You could, for example, take in eight numbers, a list of eight numbers, a list of four points each given by a tuple, a 2*4 matrix, four complex numbers, two lists of the x-coordinates and y-coordinates, and so on.

The input needs to just be the numbers in some container, with no additional data. You can't use the input to do any preprocessing, nor may you require any constraints on the input, such as requiring the points be given in ascending y coordinate. Your input must allow any eight coordinates (though your code can behave arbitrarily in the edge cases mentioned earlier).

Please state your input format.

**Output:**

Either the corresponding Boolean `True`/`False`, the corresponding number `1`/`0`, or the analogues in your language.

**Test cases**

The inputs are given a list `[X,A,B,C]` of four tuples, the test point first, then the three triangle vertices. I've grouped them into those whose outputs should be `True` and those that should be `False`.

`True` instances:

```
[(-0.31961, -0.12646), (0.38478, 0.37419), (-0.30613, -0.59754), (-0.85548, 0.6633)]
[(-0.87427, -0.00831), (0.78829, 0.60409), (-0.90904, -0.13856), (-0.80685, 0.48468)]
[(0.28997, -0.03668), (-0.28362, 0.42831), (0.39332, -0.07474), (-0.48694, -0.10497)]
[(-0.07783, 0.04415), (-0.34355, -0.07161), (0.59105, -0.93145), (0.29402, 0.90334)]
[(0.36107, 0.05389), (0.27103, 0.47754), (-0.00341, -0.79472), (0.82549, -0.29028)]
[(-0.01655, -0.20437), (-0.36194, -0.90281), (-0.26515, -0.4172), (0.36181, 0.51683)]
[(-0.12198, -0.45897), (-0.35128, -0.85405), (0.84566, 0.99364), (0.13767, 0.78618)]
[(-0.03847, -0.81531), (-0.18704, -0.33282), (-0.95717, -0.6337), (0.10976, -0.88374)]
[(0.07904, -0.06245), (0.95181, -0.84223), (-0.75583, -0.34406), (0.16785, 0.87519)]
[(-0.33485, 0.53875), (-0.25173, 0.51317), (-0.62441, -0.90698), (-0.47925, 0.74832)]
```

`False` instances:

```
[(-0.99103, 0.43842), (0.78128, -0.10985), (-0.84714, -0.20558), (-0.08925, -0.78608)]
[(0.15087, -0.56212), (-0.87374, -0.3787), (0.86403, 0.60374), (0.01392, 0.84362)]
[(0.1114, 0.66496), (-0.92633, 0.27408), (0.92439, 0.43692), (0.8298, -0.29647)]
[(0.87786, -0.8594), (-0.42283, -0.97999), (0.58659, -0.327), (-0.22656, 0.80896)]
[(0.43525, -0.8923), (0.86119, 0.78278), (-0.01348, 0.98093), (-0.56244, -0.75129)]
[(-0.73365, 0.28332), (0.63263, 0.17177), (-0.38398, -0.43497), (-0.31123, 0.73168)]
[(-0.57694, -0.87713), (-0.93622, 0.89397), (0.93117, 0.40775), (0.2323, -0.30718)]
[(0.91059, 0.75966), (0.60118, 0.73186), (0.32178, 0.88296), (-0.90087, -0.26367)]
[(0.3463, -0.89397), (0.99108, 0.13557), (0.50122, -0.8724), (0.43385, 0.00167)]
[(0.88121, 0.36469), (-0.29829, 0.21429), (0.31395, 0.2734), (0.43267, -0.78192)]
```

Comment: What is your definition of a character? Ascii? Encodable in 7 bits? In a byte? Any Unicode?

Comment: What do you suggest? There's already solutions that use compressed code.

Comment: Typically, I believe bytes are used for non-Ascii characters, because otherwise the Utf-32 advantage is insurmountable.

Comment: Well, I can't go back now; any Unicode character is a character. Compress if you want.

Answer (score 20):

## Javascript / ECMAScript 6, <strike>161</strike> <strike>159</strike> 158 / 152

Javascript:

```
function $(t,r,i,a,n,g,l,e){b=(-g*l+a*(-n+l)+i*(g-e)+n*e)/2;c=b<0?-1:1;d=(a*l-i*e+(e-a)*t+(i-l)*r)*c;f=(i*g-a*n+(a-g)*t+(n-i)*r)*c;return d>0&&f>0&&d+f<2*b*c}
```

ECMAScript 6 version (thanks m.buettner, saves 6 characters)

```
$=(t,r,i,a,n,g,l,e)=>{b=(-g*l+a*(-n+l)+i*(g-e)+n*e)/2;c=b<0?-1:1;d=(a*l-i*e+(e-a)*t+(i-l)*r)*c;f=(i*g-a*n+(a-g)*t+(n-i)*r)*c;return d>0&&f>0&&d+f<2*b*c}
```

Call it as such (returns `true` or `false`):

```
$(pointX, pointY, v1X, v1Y, v2X, v2Y, v3X, v3Y);
```

Uses some fancy [barycentric coordinate math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_%28mathematics%29) based on code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049712/863470). An ungolfed version for your reading enjoyment follows:

```
function $ (pointX, pointY, v1X, v1Y, v2X, v2Y, v3X, v3Y) {
  var A =  (-v2Y * v3X + v1Y * (-v2X + v3X) + v1X * (v2Y - v3Y) + v2X * v3Y) / 2;
  var sign = A < 0 ? -1 : 1;
  var s = (v1Y * v3X - v1X * v3Y + (v3Y - v1Y) * pointX + (v1X - v3X) * pointY) * sign;
  var t = (v1X * v2Y - v1Y * v2X + (v1Y - v2Y) * pointX + (v2X - v1X) * pointY) * sign;
  return s > 0 && t > 0 && s + t < 2 * A * sign;
}
```

Comment: +1, if only for the parameter names!

Comment: Why do you have to break my character-counting UserScript???

Comment: @kitcar2000 what do you mean?

Comment: The rules says that characters are counted, not bytes. So you can use this: http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/ to fit in 122 chars

Comment: @kitcar2000 This tool counts both characters and bytes (as per UTF-8): http://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Comment: Am I mistaken, or could you have used `(a*(l-n)+i*(g-e)+n*e-g*l)` instead of `(-g*l+a*(-n+l)+i*(g-e)+n*e)`?

Answer (score 19):

### Python 2.7 <s>128</s> <s>127</s> <s>117</s> <s>110</s> <s>109</s> <s>103</s> <s>99</s> <s>95</s> <s>94</s> <s>91</s> 90

My first code-golf attempt!

### Code

```
f=lambda x,y,t:sum(a*y+c*b+d*x<d*a+c*y+b*x for i in(0,1,2)for a,b,c,d in[t[i-1]+t[i]])%3<1
```

Takes as input (x,y,t) where (x,y) is the point we're checking and t is a triangle t = ((x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)).

### Explanation

I'm calculating the determinants of the matrices

```
| 1 x1 y1 |      | 1 x2 y2 |      | 1 x3 y3 |
| 1 x2 y2 | ,    | 1 x3 y3 | ,    | 1 x1 y1 | .
| 1 x  y  |      | 1 x  y  |      | 1 x  y  |
```

These determinants represent the signed distances from the sides of the triangle to the point (x,y). If they all have the same sign, then the point is on the same side of every line and is thus contained in the triangle.

In the code above, `a*y+c*b+d*x-d*a-c*y-b*x` is a determinant of one of these matrices.

I'm using the fact that `True+True+True==3` and `False+False+False==0` to determine if these determinants all have the same sign.

I make use of Python's negative list indices by using `t[-1]` instead of `t[(i+1)%3]`.

Thanks Peter for the idea to use `s%3<1` instead of `s in(0,3)` to check if s is either 0 or 3!

### Sagemath Version

Not really a different solution so I'm including it in this answer, a sagemath solution using **80** characters:

```
f=lambda p,t,o=[1]:sum([det(Matrix([o+t[i-1],o+t[i],o+p]))<0for i in 0,1,2])%3<1
```

where `p=[x,y]`, and `t=[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]]`

Comment: Could `s in (0,3)` be shortened to `s%3<1`?

Comment: The use of negative indices can be tweaked to save one more: `-1,0,1 ... t[i]+t[i+1]` is equivalent to `0,1,2 ... t[i-1]+t[i]`

Comment: @PeterTaylor Absolutely right! Too bad I removed the space in `in -1,0,1` before reading this. Actually your way is more readable so I'll use it anyway.

Comment: Welcome to code golf! You can get rid of the square brackets for the list comprehension inside the `sum` if you encase the `0,1,2` in parentheses, which case a character by replacing a space. The reason is that Python allow unbracketed comprehension to be passed in to functions, but the commas in the naked tuple `1,2,3` confuse it because it tries to parse them as separate arguments.

Answer (score 16):

### Mathematica, 67 bytes

```
f=Equal@@({#2,-#}&@@(#-#2).(x-#)>0&@@@Partition[x=#;#2,2,1,{1,1}])&
```

The function takes two arguments, the point `X` and a list of points `{A,B,C}`, which are referred to as `#` and `#2` respectively. That is if you call

```
f[X,{A,B,C}]
```

then you'll get `#` as `X` and `#2` as `{A,B,C}`. (Note that there are two other anonymous functions nested inside the code - `#` and `#2` have a different meaning within those.)

Here is an explanation of the function itself:

```
                                              x=#;#2            & (* Save X into a variable x, but evaluate to {A,B,C}. *)
                                    Partition[x=#;#2,2,1,{1,1}] & (* Get a cyclic list of pairs {{A,B},{B,C},{C,B}}. *)
       (                        &@@@Partition[x=#;#2,2,1,{1,1}])& (* Define an anonymous function and apply it to each 
                                                                     of the above pairs. The two elements are referred 
                                                                     to as # and #2. *)
       (          (#-#2)        &@@@Partition[x=#;#2,2,1,{1,1}])& (* Subtract the two points. For a pair of vertices 
                                                                     this yields a vector corresponding to the edge 
                                                                     between them. *)
        {#2,-#}&                                                  (* An anonymous function that takes two values, 
                                                                     reverses them, inverts the sign of one of them 
                                                                     and puts them into a list. *)
       ({#2,-#}&@@(#-#2)        &@@@Partition[x=#;#2,2,1,{1,1}])& (* Applied to the edge, this yields its normal. *)
       ({#2,-#}&@@(#-#2).(x-#)  &@@@Partition[x=#;#2,2,1,{1,1}])& (* Take the scalar product of that normal with a
                                                                     vector from a vertex to x. This is projection of 
                                                                     this vector onto that normal and hence the SIGNED
                                                                     distance of x from the edge. *)
       ({#2,-#}&@@(#-#2).(x-#)>0&@@@Partition[x=#;#2,2,1,{1,1}])& (* Check the sign of that distance, the exact mapping 
                                                                     between (left, right) and (True, False) is 
                                                                     irrelevant, as long as it's consistent. *)
Equal@@({#2,-#}&@@(#-#2).(x-#)>0&@@@Partition[x=#;#2,2,1,{1,1}])& (* Check if all signs are equal - that is, if point X 
                                                                     lies on the same side of all edges. This is 
                                                                     equivalent to check that the point is inside the 
                                                                     triangle. *)
```

Note that this function will actually work for *any* convex n-gon as long as its vertices are given in either clockwise or counter-clockwise order.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to check if the product of the distances is positive than if all of the signs are equal? I don't Mathematica, but it seems like that should be easier.

Comment: @isaacg There are three terms, so if they are all negative, their product is negative and if they are all positive, their product is positive. Your approach only works if the signs of two numbers are to be equal.

Comment: Why not use `Det`?

Comment: @alephalpha Well, mostly likely because I didn't think of it. :P ... I'll look into that

Comment: @alephalpha Hm no, I can't find a way right now to build the three required matrices in less characters.

Comment: `f[x_,a_]:=Equal@@Sign[Det/@Partition[#-x&/@a,2,1,1]]`

Comment: @alephalpha Ah, right. Feel free to post it as your own answer, I don't think I can be bothered to update mine again.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>66</s> <s>63</s> <s>59</s> <s>52</s> <s>46</s> <s>34</s> <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 28 characters

```
"Ă䒟损崙㩴ァ椟饃꿾藭鑭蘁"2G#b131b:c~
```

After transforming the Unicode string, the following code (**33 bytes**) gets evaluated:

```
{2*2/\f{f{+~@-@@-}~@@*@@*>})-!}:T
```

Expects `X [A B C]` as input, where each point is of the form `[double double]`. Output is 1 or 0.

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

A big thank you goes to [user23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/25180) for saving 6 characters (13 bytes of uncompressed code)!

#### Test cases

```
$ cat triangle.cjam
"Ă䒟损崙㩴ァ椟饃꿾藭鑭蘁"2G#b131b:c~

[
  [-0.31961 -0.12646] [ [0.38478 0.37419]   [-0.30613 -0.59754] [-0.85548 0.6633]   ] T
  [-0.87427 -0.00831] [ [0.78829 0.60409]   [-0.90904 -0.13856] [-0.80685 0.48468]  ] T
  [0.28997 -0.03668]  [ [-0.28362 0.42831]  [0.39332 -0.07474]  [-0.48694 -0.10497] ] T
  [-0.07783 0.04415]  [ [-0.34355 -0.07161] [0.59105 -0.93145]  [0.29402 0.90334]   ] T
  [0.36107 0.05389]   [ [0.27103 0.47754]   [-0.00341 -0.79472] [0.82549 -0.29028]  ] T
  [-0.01655 -0.20437] [ [-0.36194 -0.90281] [-0.26515 -0.4172]  [0.36181 0.51683]   ] T
  [-0.12198 -0.45897] [ [-0.35128 -0.85405] [0.84566 0.99364]   [0.13767 0.78618]   ] T
  [-0.03847 -0.81531] [ [-0.18704 -0.33282] [-0.95717 -0.6337]  [0.10976 -0.88374]  ] T
  [0.07904 -0.06245]  [ [0.95181 -0.84223]  [-0.75583 -0.34406] [0.16785 0.87519]   ] T
  [-0.33485 0.53875]  [ [-0.25173 0.51317]  [-0.62441 -0.90698] [-0.47925 0.74832]  ] T
  [-0.99103 0.43842]  [ [0.78128 -0.10985]  [-0.84714 -0.20558] [-0.08925 -0.78608] ] T
  [0.15087 -0.56212]  [ [-0.87374 -0.3787]  [0.86403 0.60374]   [0.01392 0.84362]   ] T
  [0.1114 0.66496]    [ [-0.92633 0.27408]  [0.92439 0.43692]   [0.8298 -0.29647]   ] T
  [0.87786 -0.8594]   [ [-0.42283 -0.97999] [0.58659 -0.327]    [-0.22656 0.80896]  ] T
  [0.43525 -0.8923]   [ [0.86119 0.78278]   [-0.01348 0.98093]  [-0.56244 -0.75129] ] T
  [-0.73365 0.28332]  [ [0.63263 0.17177]   [-0.38398 -0.43497] [-0.31123 0.73168]  ] T
  [-0.57694 -0.87713] [ [-0.93622 0.89397]  [0.93117 0.40775]   [0.2323 -0.30718]   ] T
  [0.91059 0.75966]   [ [0.60118 0.73186]   [0.32178 0.88296]   [-0.90087 -0.26367] ] T
  [0.3463 -0.89397]   [ [0.99108 0.13557]   [0.50122 -0.8724]   [0.43385 0.00167]   ] T
  [0.88121 0.36469]   [ [-0.29829 0.21429]  [0.31395 0.2734]    [0.43267 -0.78192]  ] T
]p;

$ cjam triangle.cjam
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Is that a named function?

Comment: @m.buettner: Sort of. The [official wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Data%20types%20and%20literals/) says the following: *Block - a program section delimited by `{` and `}` and treated as a single unit. Similar to code blocks in C/java, except blocks are first-class objects and can be assigned to variables (thus defining functions).*

Comment: Yes, but *did* you assign it to a variable? Otherwise I'd argue it's not "named". (I could make an anonymous function in Mathematica as well, but since the OP specified "named function" I guess I have to define it as `f` at least). Also does it return or print the result?

Comment: @m.buettner: Ah, now I get it. `{...}` defines an anonymous function and `:T` saves it in variable `T`, so yes, it is named.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that, but I didn't notice the `T`s at the end of all the lines so I was wondering how you'd be calling the function if you weren't referring to it by name. ^^

Comment: 43 bytes based on your 52 bytes and 46 bytes version, with your previous input format: ``{[_1m<@m*\]z{~f{~@~@-\@-}~@@*@@*>}%_1m<=}:T``. Or 44 bytes with your current input format: ``{[_1m<@am*\]z{~f{~@~@-\@-}~@@*@@*>}%_1m<=}:T``

Comment: Another ugly 47 bytes version before I see your update: ``{[:V1m<m*V]z{~[f{]z{:-}%[};W%]z{:*}/>}%_1m<=}:T``.

Comment: @user23013: Very clever use of `m*` and `f`! Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how to read CJam. What is your algorithm doing?

Comment: @xnor: I wanted to be sure I was done golfing before adding an explanation. I'll edit my answer in a few hours.

Comment: @xnor `1m<@m*` prepares 3 pairs of X and the next (`i+1`th) vertex of the triangle. `@-@@-` moves the current (`i`th) vertex to the origin (and mirrored if it was not `@-\@-`, but it doesn't matter). `@@*@@*>` calculates the z-axis of the cross product, aka determinant, and returns `1` if it is negative. `:+3%!` returns whether they are all the same, that is, all 3 are negative or non-negative, which means positive except for the edge cases. I think it is more challenging to read CJam than golfing.

Comment: Another two bytes can be saved with `:+3%!` replaced by `(-!`.

Comment: @user23013: I *knew* there was a shorter way, but I couldn't find it myself. Thanks again!

Comment: 37 bytes: `{[_1m<\]z\f{f{+~@-@@-}~@@*@@*>})-!}:T`. Use `2m>` or `Wm<` for Unicode safety.

Comment: @user23013: Wow! Those nested `f{...}` are pure genius.

Comment: @Dennis You didn't edit the decoded string. And although the encoded string itself is valid Unicode, the character `\7` got removed on this site. I suggest using base 134 instead of 128 to get rid of this problem.

Comment: @uswe23013: I should't edit my posts when I'm tired. It worked fine with the editor preview...

Comment: @user23013: 134 threw an exception on my machine. 135 seems to work fine.

Comment: @Dennis And it was `Xm<` when decoded...

Comment: @user23013: That's it, I'm going to bed... Thanks again!

Comment: 33 bytes: ``{2*2/\f{f{+~@-@@-}~@@*@@*>})-!}:T``

Comment: @user23013: Thanks again! We're getting to a point where Unicode compression will add chars...

Comment: @Dennis Apparently not... That point can be only 20 characters with this alternative encoding: ```"";  `":T"+  128b2A#bW%2/)W%\:+  [0X@{ _54+  @I+_Am>@\-  _Am<@+  0@-@1^ }fI]);)  @\+[~+]2A#b_2G#<!{2A#b}*  \W%+:c`"2A#b128b:c~"```, which has made this one only 25 chars. Note that some systems (like CJam itself) count them 36 characters as UTF-16.

Answer (score 5):

## C – 156 bytes

Input are array of 3 floats in X, 3 floats in Y and separate x and y for the test point. Bonus: handles all edge cases!

```
int f(float*X,float*Y,float x,float y){int i,j,c=0;for(i=0,j=2;i<3;j=i++)if(((Y[i]>y)!=(Y[j]>y))&&(x<(X[j]-X[i])*(y-Y[i])/(Y[j]-Y[i])+X[i]))c=!c;return c;}
```

Adapted from PNPOLY.

Comment: `i;j;c;f(float*X,float*Y,float x,float y){for(c=i=0,j=2;i<3;)c^=(Y[i]>y)-(Y[j]>y)&(x<(X[j]-X[i])*(y-Y[i])/(Y[j]-Y[i])+X[j=i++]);return c;}` 137 - tested in javascript

Comment: @bebe - That causes a syntax error.

Comment: That [does not](http://codepad.org/phjNyJpL) cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth 1.0.5](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/master/pyth.py), <strike>57</strike> <strike>54</strike> 51

```
DgYb=Z0J'bWbK;bDiHNR*-'H'K-@N1@K1~Z>iYJiJY=JK)R!%Z3
```

Defines the function g, which takes two inputs: the test point, and then the list of the vertices of the triangle. Outputs `True` and `False`. Note: Destroys the input, specifically b, the list of the vertices of the triangle.

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/fork/aPbXH9).
The last few characters, `gvwvw` call the function with a test case on the next two lines.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle) algorithm

Explanation:

```
DgYb                  Define g(Y,b):
=Z0                     Z=0
J'b                     J=b[0]              (No = is needed because j is special).
Wb                      While len(b)>0:     (While b:)
K;b                       K=b.pop()
DiHN                      Define i(H,N):    
R*-'H'K-@N1@K1              Return half of the linked equation.
~ZiYJiJY                  Z+=i(Y,J)>i(J,Y)
=JK                       J=K
)                       Wend
R!%Z3                   return not Z%3==0   (True iff Z == 0 or 3)
```

The CJam - Pyth war rages on!

Comment: This should be a named function. Is `w` taking STDIN input?

Comment: @xnor Oops, I missed that piece of the description. Will edit.

Comment: @xnor Are functions that print out the answer allowed, or must they return the answer? Currently, this prints out the answer, but I could have it return for one more character.

Comment: Return the answer.

Comment: Can you perhaps save characters by replacing the counter `Z` with an empty set that you accumulate with `Z|=`, then test its length to see if only `0`'s or `1` were seen? The strategy turned out longer in Python, but perhaps it's worth it using Pyth primitives.

Comment: @xnor Testing whether the length of a set is 1 is `qlZ1` - `equals(len(Z),1)`, which is the same number of characters as testing whether a number is 0 or 3, `!%Z3` - not(mod(Z,3)). So no, it wouldn't help.

Answer (score 4):

## J <strike>64</strike> 45 (42 without assignment)

```
c=:*./@(>:&0)@({.(,(1-+/))@%.|:@}.)@(}:-"1{:)
```

The assignment is not necessary for the thing to be a function, so unsure whether to count it or not.
Taking advantage of the flexible input: I'd like to have an array of (1 + number of vertices) x (dimensionality of the space).

Hoping to score some extra points here ... : This thing works for any dimension of simplex, not just triangles in a plane, but also a 3 sided pyramid in 3d space and so on. It also works when the number of vertices of the simplex is smaller than (n+1), then it computes whether the projection of the point onto the simplex is inside or not.

It converts to [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system), then checks for negative ones, indicating the point is outside.  Do mind J uses _ for negative

```
NB. example in triangle
D =: 4 2 $ 1 1 0 0 3 0 0 2 NB. 4 rows , x first, then the vertices of the triangle

NB. subtract last vertex coordinates from the rest and drop reference node
n=: (}:-"1{:)

NB. preprocessed to barycentric coordinates
bar=: {. (, 1 - +/)@%. |:@}.

NB. all positive
ap =: *./@(>:&0)

insided =: ap@bar@n

inside D
1
```

A run on the given examples:

```
   true =: 0 : 0
[(-0.31961, -0.12646), (0.38478, 0.37419), (-0.30613, -0.59754), (-0.85548, 0.6633)]
[(-0.87427, -0.00831), (0.78829, 0.60409), (-0.90904, -0.13856), (-0.80685, 0.48468)]
[(0.28997, -0.03668), (-0.28362, 0.42831), (0.39332, -0.07474), (-0.48694, -0.10497)]
[(-0.07783, 0.04415), (-0.34355, -0.07161), (0.59105, -0.93145), (0.29402, 0.90334)]
[(0.36107, 0.05389), (0.27103, 0.47754), (-0.00341, -0.79472), (0.82549, -0.29028)]
[(-0.01655, -0.20437), (-0.36194, -0.90281), (-0.26515, -0.4172), (0.36181, 0.51683)]
[(-0.12198, -0.45897), (-0.35128, -0.85405), (0.84566, 0.99364), (0.13767, 0.78618)]
[(-0.03847, -0.81531), (-0.18704, -0.33282), (-0.95717, -0.6337), (0.10976, -0.88374)]
[(0.07904, -0.06245), (0.95181, -0.84223), (-0.75583, -0.34406), (0.16785, 0.87519)]
[(-0.33485, 0.53875), (-0.25173, 0.51317), (-0.62441, -0.90698), (-0.47925, 0.74832)]
)

   false =: 0 : 0
[(-0.99103, 0.43842), (0.78128, -0.10985), (-0.84714, -0.20558), (-0.08925, -0.78608)]
[(0.15087, -0.56212), (-0.87374, -0.3787), (0.86403, 0.60374), (0.01392, 0.84362)]
[(0.1114, 0.66496), (-0.92633, 0.27408), (0.92439, 0.43692), (0.8298, -0.29647)]
[(0.87786, -0.8594), (-0.42283, -0.97999), (0.58659, -0.327), (-0.22656, 0.80896)]
[(0.43525, -0.8923), (0.86119, 0.78278), (-0.01348, 0.98093), (-0.56244, -0.75129)]
[(-0.73365, 0.28332), (0.63263, 0.17177), (-0.38398, -0.43497), (-0.31123, 0.73168)]
[(-0.57694, -0.87713), (-0.93622, 0.89397), (0.93117, 0.40775), (0.2323, -0.30718)]
[(0.91059, 0.75966), (0.60118, 0.73186), (0.32178, 0.88296), (-0.90087, -0.26367)]
[(0.3463, -0.89397), (0.99108, 0.13557), (0.50122, -0.8724), (0.43385, 0.00167)]
[(0.88121, 0.36469), (-0.29829, 0.21429), (0.31395, 0.2734), (0.43267, -0.78192)]
)
   NB. replace - by _ to avoid problems
   NB. cut up per row, drop the [ ] and convert to numbers
   $dat_t =: ((4 2 $ ".)@}:@}.;._2) (true='-')} true ,: '_'
10 4 2
   $dat_f =: ((4 2 $ ".)@}:@}.;._2) (false='-')}false,: '_'
10 4 2
   NB. this results in arrays with shape 10 4 2

   NB. for each 4 x 2 array (rank 2), do c for all true instances
   c=:*./@(>:&0)@({.(,(1-+/))@%.|:@}.)@(}:-"1{:)
   c"2 dat_t
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   NB. the same for the false ones, demonstrating anonymous usage
   NB. still a function though (or verb in J parlance)
   *./@(>:&0)@({.(,(1-+/))@%.|:@}.)@(}:-"1{:)"2 dat_f
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I asked for a named function, so the assignment characters count. Here are some points for generalizing to polygons!  ······

Comment: Well, actually, I don't quite generalize to polygons, but to N-dimensional simplexes, with maximum `N+1` vertices. For instance a 4 vertex pyramid in 3-D space, or a 5 vertex simplex in 4-D space. The number of vertices can be lower  than `N+1`, in which case the algorithm looks whether the orthogonal projection onto the hyperplane the simplex resides in lies inside the simplex or not (eg a 2 point simplex in 2-D will be projected on the line and checked whether this projection lies between the end points)

Answer (score 4):

### HTML5 + JS, 13b + 146b / 141b / 114 chars

HTML:

```
<canvas id=C>
```

JS (146b):

```
// @params: t1x, t1y, t2x, t2y, t3x, t3y, pointx, pointy
function T(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h){with(C.getContext("2d"))return beginPath(),moveTo(a,b),lineTo(c,d),lineTo(e,f),fill(),!!getImageData(g,h,1,1).data[3]}
```

or ES6 (141b):

```
T=(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)=>{with(C.getContext("2d"))return beginPath(),moveTo(a,b),lineTo(c,d),lineTo(e,f),fill(),!!getImageData(g,h,1,1).data[3]}
```

or ES6 unicode-obfuscated (114 chars):

```
eval(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/xH8mV/

Unicode obfuscation made with:
http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/

Comment: It doesn't seem to yield the correct result when the point is close to the side: http://jsfiddle.net/L2B2A/ I believe this is because all inputs are between (-1,1), and your code is only testing the 4 pixels around the origin.

Comment: that's right, to fit the examples, I should change the origin and the scale of my canvas to handle triangles inside [-1,1]. But why are those triangles so small anyways?

Comment: the problem says that all x y are between -1 and 1. Don't really know why, but I believe you can just multiply every input by 1e7 (to maintain precision) can get the correct result :D

Comment: A graphical solution, very clever!

Answer (score 3):

## Python (65)

People seem to be done submitting, so I'll post my own solution to my question.

```python
f=lambda X,L:sum(((L[i-1]-X)/(L[i]-X)).imag>0for i in(0,1,2))%3<1
```

`X` is the complex number representing the test points, and `L` is a list of three points, each a complex number.

First, I'll explain a less golfed version of the code;

```python
def f(X,A,B,C):A-=X;B-=X;C-=X;return((A/B).imag>0)==((B/C).imag>0)==((C/A).imag>0)
```

We shift the points `A,B,C,X` so that `X` is at the origin, taking advantage of Python's built-in complex arithmetic. We need to check if the origin is contained in the convex hull of `A,B,C`. This is equivalent to the origin always lying on the same side (left or right) of the line segments AB, BC, and AC.

A segment `AB` has the origin on the left if one travel counterclockwise less than 180 degrees to get from A to B, and on the right otherwise. If we consider the angles `a`, `b`, and `c` corresponding to these points, this means `b-a < 180 degrees` (taken angles in the range 0 to 360 degrees). As complex numbers, `angle(B/A)=angle(B)/angle(A)`. Also, `angle(x) < 180 degrees` exactly for point in he upper half-plane, which we check via `imag(x)>0`.

So whether the origin lies to the left of AB is expressed as `(A/B).imag>0`. Checking whether these are all equal for each cyclic pair in `A,B,C` tells us whether triangle `ABC` contains the origin.

Now, let's return to the fully golfed code

```python
f=lambda X,L:sum(((L[i-1]-X)/(L[i]-X)).imag>0for i in(0,1,2))%3<1
```

We generate each cyclic pair in `(A-X,B-X,C-X)=(L[0]-X,L[1]-X,L[2]-X)`, taking advantage of negative Python list indices wrapping around (`L[-1]` = `L[2]`). To check that the Bools are all `True` (`1`) or all `False` (`0`), we add them and check divisibility by 3, as many solutions did.

Answer (score 2):

## Fortran - <s>232</s> <s>218</s> <s>195</s> 174

Bloody awful. The function is horrendous because of the requirement that the data is passed to it and we cannot preprocess it.

```
logical function L(x);real::x(8);p=x(1)-x(3);q=x(2)-x(4);r=x(5)-x(3);s=x(6)-x(4);t=x(7)-x(3);u=x(8)-x(4);L=ALL([p*(s-u)+q*(t-r)+r*u-t*s,p*u-q*t,q*r-p*s]>=r*u-t*s);endfunction
```

The decrease of 14 characters is because I forgot to golf the function name from my test runs. The further decrease is due to implicit typing and forgetting to change the function name. The next 20 characters came off due to reading in the points as a single array. The full program is

```
program inTriagle
   real, dimension(2) :: a,b,c,x
   do 
      print*,"Enter coordinates as x,a,b,c"
      read*,x,a,b,c
      if(all(x==0.0).and.all(a==0.0).and.all(b==0.0).and.all(c==0.0)) exit
      print*,"Is point in triangle: ",T(x,a,b,c)
   enddo
 contains!                       
   logical function L(x)
     real::x(8)
     p=x(1)-x(3);q=x(2)-x(4);r=x(5)-x(3)
     s=x(6)-x(4);t=x(7)-x(3);u=x(8)-x(4)
     L=ALL([p*(s-u)+q*(t-r)+r*u-t*s,p*u-q*t,q*r-p*s]>=r*u-t*s)
   endfunction
end program inTriagle
```

Comment: You can make this a bit shorter by relying on Fortran's implicit typing and using a single input array containing all 8 numbers: `logical function T(x);real x(8);p=x(1)-x(3);q=x(2)-x(4);r=x(5)-x(3);s=x(6)-x(4);u=x(7)-x(3);v=x(8)-x(4);o=r*v-u*s;T=ALL([p*(s-v)+q*(u-r)+o,p*v-q*u,q*r-p*s]>=o);end` I've tried shortening this further by using list operations, but unfortunately that didn't work out very well.

Comment: Even shorter by eliminating more common subexpressions: `logical function T(x);real x(8);p=x(1)-x(3);q=x(2)-x(4);r=x(5)-x(3);s=x(6)-x(4);u=x(7)-x(3);v=x(8)-x(4);a=r*v-u*s;b=p*v-q*u;d=q*r-p*s;T=ALL([a-b-d,b,d]>=a);end` I hope I didn't make any mistakes in the transformations! Though it looks like your original code doesn't pass all testcases.

Comment: @Ventero: I can't believe I forgot to abuse implicit typing :(. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ventero: Also, it seems my answer depends on the orientation of the triangle. The first `True` example in OP gives `False` if I swap `B` and `C`'s values while giving `True` for the original orientation.

Comment: Ah, indeed, the problem is caused when (re-using the notation from my previous comment) `a < 0`, which effectively inverts the condition you have to test. Unfortunately this can't just be fixed by wrapping everything in an `abs`, as then the implied condition of `b` and `d` having the same sign as `a` gets lost. This can be fixed by using something like (again, re-using the notation and pre-defined variables from my last comment) `e=a-b-d;T=ALL([a*a-b*b,a*a-d*d,a*a-e*e,a*b,a*d,a*e]>=0)` - which probably can be golfed more.

Comment: By normalizing `b` and `d` over `a`, the condition can be shortened to `T=ALL([b,d,1-b-d]>=0)`, for a total of 167 characters while passing all testcases.

Answer (score 2):

## C# 218 (149?)

```
using P=System.Drawing.PointF;
bool F(P[]p){for(int i=0;i<4;i++){p[i].X*=1e7f;p[i].Y*=1e7f;}P[]a=new P[3];Array.Copy(p,1,a,0,3);var g=new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();g.AddLines(a);return g.IsVisible(p[0]);}
```

Probably not as character-efficient as a mathematical method, but it's a fun use of libraries. Incidentally, also rather slow.

Also taking advantage of "Also don't worry about numerical stability or floating-point precision." - unfortunately, `GraphicsPath` uses `int`s internally, so a value in the range -1 < f < 1 can only have three possible values. Since floats only have 7 digits of precision, I just multiply by 1e7 to turn them into whole numbers. Hm, I guess it's not really *losing* any precision. It's also exploitable in another way: I probably could have taken advantage of ignoring precision and just given the "wrong" answer.

*If* I'm allowed to ignore the character cost of importing libraries, **149** (at the very least, `System.Linq` and `System.Drawing` are pretty standard on most WinForms projects, but `System.Drawing.Drawing2D` might be a bit of a stretch):

```
bool G(PointF[]p){for(int i=0;i<4;i++){p[i].X*=1e7f;p[i].Y*=1e7f;}var g=new GraphicsPath();g.AddLines(p.Skip(1).ToArray());return g.IsVisible(p[0]);}
```

Test program (yea, it's ugly):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using P=System.Drawing.PointF;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prog = new Program();
        foreach (string test in
@"[(-0.31961, -0.12646), (0.38478, 0.37419), (-0.30613, -0.59754), (-0.85548, 0.6633)]
[(-0.87427, -0.00831), (0.78829, 0.60409), (-0.90904, -0.13856), (-0.80685, 0.48468)]
[(0.28997, -0.03668), (-0.28362, 0.42831), (0.39332, -0.07474), (-0.48694, -0.10497)]
[(-0.07783, 0.04415), (-0.34355, -0.07161), (0.59105, -0.93145), (0.29402, 0.90334)]
[(0.36107, 0.05389), (0.27103, 0.47754), (-0.00341, -0.79472), (0.82549, -0.29028)]
[(-0.01655, -0.20437), (-0.36194, -0.90281), (-0.26515, -0.4172), (0.36181, 0.51683)]
[(-0.12198, -0.45897), (-0.35128, -0.85405), (0.84566, 0.99364), (0.13767, 0.78618)]
[(-0.03847, -0.81531), (-0.18704, -0.33282), (-0.95717, -0.6337), (0.10976, -0.88374)]
[(0.07904, -0.06245), (0.95181, -0.84223), (-0.75583, -0.34406), (0.16785, 0.87519)]
[(-0.33485, 0.53875), (-0.25173, 0.51317), (-0.62441, -0.90698), (-0.47925, 0.74832)]
[(-0.99103, 0.43842), (0.78128, -0.10985), (-0.84714, -0.20558), (-0.08925, -0.78608)]
[(0.15087, -0.56212), (-0.87374, -0.3787), (0.86403, 0.60374), (0.01392, 0.84362)]
[(0.1114, 0.66496), (-0.92633, 0.27408), (0.92439, 0.43692), (0.8298, -0.29647)]
[(0.87786, -0.8594), (-0.42283, -0.97999), (0.58659, -0.327), (-0.22656, 0.80896)]
[(0.43525, -0.8923), (0.86119, 0.78278), (-0.01348, 0.98093), (-0.56244, -0.75129)]
[(-0.73365, 0.28332), (0.63263, 0.17177), (-0.38398, -0.43497), (-0.31123, 0.73168)]
[(-0.57694, -0.87713), (-0.93622, 0.89397), (0.93117, 0.40775), (0.2323, -0.30718)]
[(0.91059, 0.75966), (0.60118, 0.73186), (0.32178, 0.88296), (-0.90087, -0.26367)]
[(0.3463, -0.89397), (0.99108, 0.13557), (0.50122, -0.8724), (0.43385, 0.00167)]
[(0.88121, 0.36469), (-0.29829, 0.21429), (0.31395, 0.2734), (0.43267, -0.78192)]".Split('\n'))
        {
            string t = test.Replace("[(", "").Replace(")]", "");
            string[] points = t.Split(new string[] { "), (" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            string[] p = points[0].Split(',');
            P[] xabc = new P[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                p = points[i].Split(',');
                xabc[i] = new F(float.Parse(p[0]), float.Parse(p[1]));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(test + "=>" + prog.F(xabc));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    bool G(PointF[]p)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){p[i].X*=1e7f;p[i].Y*=1e7f;}
        var g=new GraphicsPath();
        g.AddLines(p.Skip(1).ToArray());
        return g.IsVisible(p[0]);
    }

    bool F(P[]p)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){p[i].X*=1e7f;p[i].Y*=1e7f;}
        var g=new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        g.AddLines(p.Skip(1).ToArray());
        return g.IsVisible(p[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cute, getting the drawing engine to do the work.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB: 9!

Not a whole lot of me to write here

```
inpolygon
```

Can be called like so:

```
inpolygon(2/3, 2/3, [0 1 1], [0 0 1])
```

Output is assigned to a variable named `ans`

---

If I actually had to write a function, it may be something like so, could probably be optimized:

```
function y=f(a,b,c,d)
inpolygon(a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: can be shorter using a function handle: `f=@(a,b,c,d)inpolygon(a,b,c,d)`

Answer (score 2):

#### Haskell — <s>233</s> 127

Using cross products as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51328):

```
h(a,b)(p,q)(r,s)(t,u)=z a b p q r s==z a b r s t u&&z a b r s t u==z a b t u p q where z j k l m n o =(o-m)*(j-l)+(l-n)*(k-m)>0
```

Previous solution implemented using [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Determining_whether_a_point_is_inside_a_triangle) and the formulae described in this Stack Exchange [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51459):

```
g(p,q)(r,s)(t,u)(v,w)=
 let (j,k)=(p+(-r),q+(-s))
     (l,m)=(t+(-r),u+(-s))
     (n,o)=(v+(-r),w+(-s))
     d=l*o-n*m
     a=(j*(m-o)+k*(n-l)+l*o-n*m)/d
     b=(j*o-k*n)/d
     c=(k*l-j*m)/d
 in (0<=a&&a<1)&&(0<=b&&b<1)&&(0<=c&&c<1)
```

Both functions `g` and `h` take four pairs, the first of which is the point to be tested for inclusion and the rest being the coordinates of the vertices of the triangle.

To test with the sample input:

```
let trueTestCases =
  [((-0.31961, -0.12646), (0.38478, 0.37419), (-0.30613, -0.59754), (-0.85548, 0.6633)),
   ((-0.87427, -0.00831), (0.78829, 0.60409), (-0.90904, -0.13856), (-0.80685, 0.48468)),
   ((0.28997, -0.03668), (-0.28362, 0.42831), (0.39332, -0.07474), (-0.48694, -0.10497)),
   ((-0.07783, 0.04415), (-0.34355, -0.07161), (0.59105, -0.93145), (0.29402, 0.90334)),
   ((0.36107, 0.05389), (0.27103, 0.47754), (-0.00341, -0.79472), (0.82549, -0.29028)),
   ((-0.01655, -0.20437), (-0.36194, -0.90281), (-0.26515, -0.4172), (0.36181, 0.51683)),
   ((-0.12198, -0.45897), (-0.35128, -0.85405), (0.84566, 0.99364), (0.13767, 0.78618)),
   ((-0.03847, -0.81531), (-0.18704, -0.33282), (-0.95717, -0.6337), (0.10976, -0.88374)),
   ((0.07904, -0.06245), (0.95181, -0.84223), (-0.75583, -0.34406), (0.16785, 0.87519)),
   ((-0.33485, 0.53875), (-0.25173, 0.51317), (-0.62441, -0.90698), (-0.47925, 0.74832))]

let falseTestCases =
  [((-0.99103, 0.43842), (0.78128, -0.10985), (-0.84714, -0.20558), (-0.08925, -0.78608)),
   ((0.15087, -0.56212), (-0.87374, -0.3787), (0.86403, 0.60374), (0.01392, 0.84362)),
   ((0.1114, 0.66496), (-0.92633, 0.27408), (0.92439, 0.43692), (0.8298, -0.29647)),
   ((0.87786, -0.8594), (-0.42283, -0.97999), (0.58659, -0.327), (-0.22656, 0.80896)),
   ((0.43525, -0.8923), (0.86119, 0.78278), (-0.01348, 0.98093), (-0.56244, -0.75129)),
   ((-0.73365, 0.28332), (0.63263, 0.17177), (-0.38398, -0.43497), (-0.31123, 0.73168)),
   ((-0.57694, -0.87713), (-0.93622, 0.89397), (0.93117, 0.40775), (0.2323, -0.30718)),
   ((0.91059, 0.75966), (0.60118, 0.73186), (0.32178, 0.88296), (-0.90087, -0.26367)),
   ((0.3463, -0.89397), (0.99108, 0.13557), (0.50122, -0.8724), (0.43385, 0.00167)),
   ((0.88121, 0.36469), (-0.29829, 0.21429), (0.31395, 0.2734), (0.43267, -0.78192))]

type Point = (Double, Double)

test :: [(Point, Point, Point, Point)] -> [Bool]
test testCases =
  map (\((px,py),(ax,ay),(bx,by),(cx,cy)) -> h (px,py) (ax,ay) (bx,by) (cx,cy)) testCases

test trueTestCases --> [True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True]
test falseTestCases --> [False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
```

Ungolfed solutions:

```
type Point = (Double, Double)

-- using cross products

triangulate' (a, b) (p, q) (r, s) (t, u) =
  (side a b p q r s == side a b r s t u) && (side a b r s t u == side a b t u p q)
  where side j k l m n o = (o - m) * (j - l) + (-n + l) * (k - m) >= 0

-- using barycentric coordinates

triangulate :: (Point, Point, Point, Point) -> Bool
triangulate ((px, py), (ax, ay), (bx, by), (cx, cy)) = 
  let (p'x, p'y) = (px + (-ax), py + (-ay))
      (b'x, b'y) = (bx + (-ax), by + (-ay))
      (c'x, c'y) = (cx + (-ax), cy + (-ay))
      d = b'x * c'y - c'x * b'y
      a = (p'x * (b'y - c'y) + p'y * (c'x - b'x) + b'x * c'y - c'x * b'y) / d
      b = (p'x * c'y - p'y * c'x) / d
      c = (p'y * b'x - p'x * b'y) / d
  in
      (0 <= a && a < 1) && (0 <= b && b < 1) && (0 <= c && c < 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 120

```
C=(p,q,i,j,k,l,m,n,
 z=j*(m-k)+i*(l-n)+k*n-l*m,
 s=(j*m-i*n+(n-j)*p+(i-m)*q)/z,
 t=(i*l-j*k+(j-l)*p+(k-i)*q)/z
)=>s>0&t>0&s+t<1
```

Directly copied from my answer to [This other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40343/triangular-battleships-a-computational-geometry-problem)

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

*Output* all 1s

```
;[
C(-0.31961, -0.12646, 0.38478, 0.37419, -0.30613, -0.59754, -0.85548, 0.6633),
C(-0.87427, -0.00831, 0.78829, 0.60409, -0.90904, -0.13856, -0.80685, 0.48468),
C(0.28997, -0.03668, -0.28362, 0.42831, 0.39332, -0.07474, -0.48694, -0.10497),
C(-0.07783, 0.04415, -0.34355, -0.07161, 0.59105, -0.93145, 0.29402, 0.90334),
C(0.36107, 0.05389, 0.27103, 0.47754, -0.00341, -0.79472, 0.82549, -0.29028),
C(-0.01655, -0.20437, -0.36194, -0.90281, -0.26515, -0.4172, 0.36181, 0.51683),
C(-0.12198, -0.45897, -0.35128, -0.85405, 0.84566, 0.99364, 0.13767, 0.78618),
C(-0.03847, -0.81531, -0.18704, -0.33282, -0.95717, -0.6337, 0.10976, -0.88374),
C(0.07904, -0.06245, 0.95181, -0.84223, -0.75583, -0.34406, 0.16785, 0.87519),
C(-0.33485, 0.53875, -0.25173, 0.51317, -0.62441, -0.90698, -0.47925, 0.74832)
]
```

*Output* all 0s

```
;[
C(-0.99103, 0.43842,0.78128, -0.10985,-0.84714, -0.20558,-0.08925, -0.78608),
C(0.15087, -0.56212,-0.87374, -0.3787,0.86403, 0.60374,0.01392, 0.84362),
C(0.1114, 0.66496,-0.92633, 0.27408,0.92439, 0.43692,0.8298, -0.29647),
C(0.87786, -0.8594,-0.42283, -0.97999,0.58659, -0.327,-0.22656, 0.80896),
C(0.43525, -0.8923,0.86119, 0.78278,-0.01348, 0.98093,-0.56244, -0.75129),
C(-0.73365, 0.28332,0.63263, 0.17177,-0.38398, -0.43497,-0.31123, 0.73168),
C(-0.57694, -0.87713,-0.93622, 0.89397,0.93117, 0.40775,0.2323, -0.30718),
C(0.91059, 0.75966,0.60118, 0.73186,0.32178, 0.88296,-0.90087, -0.26367),
C(0.3463, -0.89397,0.99108, 0.13557,0.50122, -0.8724,0.43385, 0.00167),
C(0.88121, 0.36469,-0.29829, 0.21429,0.31395, 0.2734,0.43267, -0.78192)
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, <s>111</s> 100 characters

```
DEF T X,Y,A,B,C,D,E,F
Q=9e5GCLS
GTRI(A-X)*Q,Q*(B-Y),Q*(C-X),Q*(D-Y),Q*(E-X),Q*(F-Y)?!!GSPOIT(0,0)END
```

Draws a triangle and checks the color of the pixel at the point.
The triangle is scaled up 99999x and shifted so that the point to check will be at (0,0) before being drawn, to minimize loss in precision.

Answer (score 2):

## Intel 8087 FPU assembly, <del>222</del> 220 bytes

Uses only the 8087 FPU hardware to calculate.  Here is the unassembled (ungolfed in this case too) version as a MACRO (will spare you the 220 hex byte codes):

```
; calculate the area of of a triangle ABC using determinate
; input: coordinates (float), Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy
; output: area in ST
TAREA   MACRO   A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2
    FLD  A1
    FLD  B2
    FLD  C2
    FSUB        ; ST = By - Cy
    FMUL        ; ST = Ax * ( By - Cy )
    FLD  B1 
    FLD  C2
    FLD  A2
    FSUB        ; ST = Cy - Ay
    FMUL        ; ST = Bx * ( Cy - Ay )
    FLD  C1
    FLD  A2
    FLD  B2
    FSUB        ; Ay - By
    FMUL        ; Cx * ( Ay - By )
    FADD        ; Cx * ( Ay - By ) + Bx * ( Cy - Ay )
    FADD        ; Cx * ( Ay - By ) + Bx * ( Cy - Ay ) + Ax * ( By - Cy )
    FLD1        ; make a value of 2
    FADD ST,ST  ; ST = 2
    FDIV        ; divide by 2
    FABS        ; take abs value
        ENDM

; determine if point X is in triangle ABC
; input: points X, A, B, C
; output: ZF=1 if X in triangle, ZF=0 if X not in triangle
TXINABC     MACRO X1,X2,A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2

    TAREA  A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2    ; ST(3) = area of triangle ABC
    TAREA  X1,X2,B1,B2,C1,C2    ; ST(2) = area of triangle XBC
    TAREA  A1,A2,X1,X2,C1,C2    ; ST(1) = area of triangle AXC
    TAREA  A1,A2,B1,B2,X1,X2    ; ST(0) = area of triangle ABX

    FADD        ; add areas of triangles with point
    FADD        ; ST = ST + ST(1) + ST(2)
    FCOMPP      ; compare ST to ST(1) and pop results
    FWAIT       ; sync CPU/FPU
    FSTSW R     ; store result flags to R
    MOV  AX, R  ; move result to AX
    SAHF        ; store result into CPU flags for conditional check
        ENDM
```

### Explanation

Uses the determinate to calculate the area of the ABC triangle, and then the triangle formed with the X point and two other points of the ABC triangle.  If the area of triangle ABC equals the sum of areas of triangles XBC + AXC + ABX, then the point is within the triangle.  The result is returned as ZF.

#### What's neat about this

All of the math and floating point operations are done in hardware with 80-bit extended precision.  The final floating point comparison is also done in hardware so will be very accurate.

This also uses all eight of the 8087's stack registers at once.

#### What's not quite as neat about this

As the points of the triangle must be plugged back into the formulas several times during the calculation, it requires each variable in memory to be loaded into the FPU's stack registers one at a time in the correct order.  While this can be fairly easily modeled like a function as a MACRO, it means that the code is expanded each time at assembly, creating redundant code.  41 bytes were saved by moving some of the same repeated code segments into PROCs.  However it makes the code less readable, so the above listing is without it (which is why it's labeled as "ungolfed").

### Tests

Here is a test program using IBM DOS showing output:

```
TTEST   MACRO T
        LOCAL IS_IN_TRI

    TXINABC T,T+4*1,T+4*2,T+4*3,T+4*4,T+4*5,T+4*6,T+4*7
    MOV  DX, OFFSET TEQ     ; load true string by default 
    JZ   IS_IN_TRI          ; if ZF=1, it is in triangle, skip to display
    MOV  DX, OFFSET FEQ     ; otherwise ZF=0 means not in triangle, so load false string
IS_IN_TRI:
    MOV  AH, 9              ; DOS write string function
    INT  21H 
        ENDM

START:
    FINIT                   ; reset 8087

    TTEST   T0              ; true tests
    TTEST   T1
    TTEST   T2
    TTEST   T3
    TTEST   T4
    TTEST   T5
    TTEST   T6
    TTEST   T7
    TTEST   T8
    TTEST   T9

    TTEST   F0              ; false tests
    TTEST   F1
    TTEST   F2
    TTEST   F3
    TTEST   F4
    TTEST   F5
    TTEST   F6  
    TTEST   F7
    TTEST   F8  
    TTEST   F9

    RET         ; return to DOS

T0  DD  -0.31961, -0.12646, 0.38478, 0.37419, -0.30613, -0.59754, -0.85548, 0.6633
T1  DD  -0.87427, -0.00831, 0.78829, 0.60409, -0.90904, -0.13856, -0.80685, 0.48468
T2  DD  0.28997, -0.03668, -0.28362, 0.42831, 0.39332, -0.07474, -0.48694, -0.10497
T3  DD  -0.07783, 0.04415, -0.34355, -0.07161, 0.59105, -0.93145, 0.29402, 0.90334
T4  DD  0.36107, 0.05389, 0.27103, 0.47754, -0.00341, -0.79472, 0.82549, -0.29028
T5  DD  -0.01655, -0.20437, -0.36194, -0.90281, -0.26515, -0.4172, 0.36181, 0.51683
T6  DD  -0.12198, -0.45897, -0.35128, -0.85405, 0.84566, 0.99364, 0.13767, 0.78618
T7  DD  -0.03847, -0.81531, -0.18704, -0.33282, -0.95717, -0.6337, 0.10976, -0.88374
T8  DD  0.07904, -0.06245, 0.95181, -0.84223, -0.75583, -0.34406, 0.16785, 0.87519
T9  DD  -0.33485, 0.53875, -0.25173, 0.51317, -0.62441, -0.90698, -0.47925, 0.74832

F0  DD  -0.99103, 0.43842, 0.78128, -0.10985, -0.84714, -0.20558, -0.08925, -0.78608
F1  DD  0.15087, -0.56212, -0.87374, -0.3787, 0.86403, 0.60374, 0.01392, 0.84362
F2  DD  0.1114, 0.66496, -0.92633, 0.27408, 0.92439, 0.43692, 0.8298, -0.29647
F3  DD  0.87786, -0.8594, -0.42283, -0.97999, 0.58659, -0.327, -0.22656, 0.80896
F4  DD  0.43525, -0.8923, 0.86119, 0.78278, -0.01348, 0.98093, -0.56244, -0.75129
F5  DD  -0.73365, 0.28332, 0.63263, 0.17177, -0.38398, -0.43497, -0.31123, 0.73168
F6  DD  -0.57694, -0.87713, -0.93622, 0.89397, 0.93117, 0.40775, 0.2323, -0.30718
F7  DD  0.91059, 0.75966, 0.60118, 0.73186, 0.32178, 0.88296, -0.90087, -0.26367
F8  DD  0.3463, -0.89397, 0.99108, 0.13557, 0.50122, -0.8724, 0.43385, 0.00167
F9  DD  0.88121, 0.36469, -0.29829, 0.21429, 0.31395, 0.2734, 0.43267, -0.78192

TEQ DB 'In Triangle',0DH,0AH,'$'
FEQ DB 'Not In Triangle',0DH,0AH,'$'
```

#### Output

```
In Triangle
In Triangle
In Triangle
In Triangle
In Triangle
In Triangle
In Triangle
In Triangle
In Triangle
In Triangle
Not In Triangle
Not In Triangle
Not In Triangle
Not In Triangle
Not In Triangle
Not In Triangle
Not In Triangle
Not In Triangle
Not In Triangle
Not In Triangle
```

Answer (score 1):

### C 414 (was 465)

Golfed

```
#define D double 
int F(D ax,D ay,D bx,D by,D cx,D cy,D px,D py){int y=0;double J,K;D m=(ax-bx<0.001)?(by-ay)/(ax-bx):1000;D b=m*ax+ay;J=m*cx-cy+b;K=m*px-py+b;if(J*K>=0)y=1;return y;}D T[8],k;int i,n;void G(){while(i<8){scanf("%lf",&k);T[i++]=k;}n+=F(T[2],T[3],T[4],T[5],T[6],T[7],T[0],T[1]);n+=F(T[4],T[5],T[6],T[7],T[2],T[3],T[0],T[1]);n+=F(T[2],T[3],T[6],T[7],T[4],T[5],T[0],T[1]);printf(n==3?"True":"False");}
```

Original function declaration added for explanation

```
/**
* determine if points C & P are on same side of line AB
* return 1 if true, 0 otherwise
*/
int PointsSameSide(D ax,D ay,D bx,D by,D cx, D cy, D px, D py);
```

Rewritten as a named function: input via stdin one each line or all in one line space-separated.

```
#define D double
int F(D ax,D ay,D bx,D by,D cx, D cy, D px, D py)
{
int y=0;
double J,K;
D m = (ax-bx<0.001)?(by-ay)/(ax-bx):1000;
D b = m*ax+ay;
J=m*cx-cy+b;
K=m*px-py+b;
if(J*K>=0)y=1;
return y;
}
double T[8],k;
int i,n;
void G()
{
while(i<8){scanf("%lf",&k);T[i++]=k;}
n+=F(T[2],T[3],T[4],T[5],T[6],T[7],T[0],T[1]);
n+=F(T[4],T[5],T[6],T[7],T[2],T[3],T[0],T[1]);
n+=F(T[2],T[3],T[6],T[7],T[4],T[5],T[0],T[1]);
printf(n==3?"True":"False");
}
```

Comment: You could save some bytes by getting rid of newlines and unnecessary spaces. Also, you have `double` redefined as `D` but you still use `double` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 125/198

If points are provided in 8 arguments:

```
function d(x,y,a,b,c,d,e,f){function z(a,b,c,d){return(y-b)*(c-a)-(x-a)*(d-b)>0}return(z(a,b,c,d)+z(c,d,e,f)+z(e,f,a,b))%3<1}
```

If points are provided in a 2-dimensional array:

```
function c(s){return (z(s[1][0],s[1][1],s[2][0],s[2][1])+z(s[2][0],s[2][1],s[3][0],s[3][1])+z(s[3][0],s[3][1],s[1][0],s[1][1]))%3<1;function z(a,b,c,d){return (s[0][1]-b)*(c-a)-(s[0][0]-a)*(d-b)>0}}
```

This code doesn't use any of those fancy vector math. Instead, it only uses a simple algebra trick to determine if the point is inside the triangle or not. The formula:

```
(y-b)(c-a) - (x-a)(d-b)
```

[which tells the point is on which side of a line](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pmuc3meieh), is derived from rearranging the definition of slope:

```
            m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
      (y2-y1) = m(x2-x1)
       (y-y1) = m(x-x1)     ,substituting point we are testing (x,y) to be the 2nd point
       (y-y1) = (x-x1)(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)  ,substitute back the original definition of m
(y-y1)(x2-x1) = (x-x1)(y2-y1)    <-- left side will be greater than the right side, if
                                     the point is on the left; otherwise, it's on the right
            0 = (y-b)(c-a)-(x-a)(d-b) ,where (a,b)=(x1,y1), (c,d)=(x2,y2)
```

If we test all 3 sides, all 3 should yield some numbers with the same sign only when the point is inside the triangle since we are testing it around the triangle. If the point is on a side then one of the test should return 0.

jsFiddle test code: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/zEzZU/

```
var l = [[-0.31961, -0.12646, 0.38478, 0.37419, -0.30613, -0.59754, -0.85548, 0.6633],[-0.87427, -0.00831, 0.78829, 0.60409, -0.90904, -0.13856, -0.80685, 0.48468],[0.28997, -0.03668, -0.28362, 0.42831, 0.39332, -0.07474, -0.48694, -0.10497],[-0.07783, 0.04415, -0.34355, -0.07161, 0.59105, -0.93145, 0.29402, 0.90334],[0.36107, 0.05389, 0.27103, 0.47754, -0.00341, -0.79472, 0.82549, -0.29028],[-0.01655, -0.20437, -0.36194, -0.90281, -0.26515, -0.4172, 0.36181, 0.51683],[-0.12198, -0.45897, -0.35128, -0.85405, 0.84566, 0.99364, 0.13767, 0.78618],[-0.03847, -0.81531, -0.18704, -0.33282, -0.95717, -0.6337, 0.10976, -0.88374],[0.07904, -0.06245, 0.95181, -0.84223, -0.75583, -0.34406, 0.16785, 0.87519],[-0.33485, 0.53875, -0.25173, 0.51317, -0.62441, -0.90698, -0.47925, 0.74832],
         [-0.99103, 0.43842, 0.78128, -0.10985, -0.84714, -0.20558, -0.08925, -0.78608],[0.15087, -0.56212, -0.87374, -0.3787, 0.86403, 0.60374, 0.01392, 0.84362],[0.1114, 0.66496, -0.92633, 0.27408, 0.92439, 0.43692, 0.8298, -0.29647],[0.87786, -0.8594, -0.42283, -0.97999, 0.58659, -0.327, -0.22656, 0.80896],[0.43525, -0.8923, 0.86119, 0.78278, -0.01348, 0.98093, -0.56244, -0.75129],[-0.73365, 0.28332, 0.63263, 0.17177, -0.38398, -0.43497, -0.31123, 0.73168],[-0.57694, -0.87713, -0.93622, 0.89397, 0.93117, 0.40775, 0.2323, -0.30718],[0.91059, 0.75966, 0.60118, 0.73186, 0.32178, 0.88296, -0.90087, -0.26367],[0.3463, -0.89397, 0.99108, 0.13557, 0.50122, -0.8724, 0.43385, 0.00167],[0.88121, 0.36469, -0.29829, 0.21429, 0.31395, 0.2734, 0.43267, -0.78192]];

function d(x,y,a,b,c,d,e,f){function z(a,b,c,d){return(y-b)*(c-a)-(x-a)*(d-b)>0}return(z(a,b,c,d)+z(c,d,e,f)+z(e,f,a,b))%3<1}

for(var i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
    console.log(d.apply(undefined,l[i]));    //10 true, 10 false
}
```

---

**97 characters** (not counting spaces or tabs) count if converted into CoffeeScript:

```
d=(x,y,a,b,c,d,e,f)->
    z=(a,b,c,d)->
        (y-b)*(c-a)-(x-a)*(d-b)>0
    (z(a,b,c,d)+z(c,d,e,f)+z(e,f,a,b))%3<1
```

**115 characters** if converted into ES6:

```
d=(x,y,a,b,c,d,e,f)=>{z=(a,b,c,d)=>{return (y-b)*(c-a)-(x-a)*(d-b)>0};return(z(a,b,c,d)+z(c,d,e,f)+z(e,f,a,b))%3<1}
```

Comment: That *is* the "fancy vector math" I'm using :D (not the fancy barycentric coordinate approach some others took, though). Like the top-voted answer, you can save a few bytes by using ES6 and defining the functions like `d=(x,y,...)=>{...}`. In your case, you can save even more by using CoffeeScript, which doesn't need `return`: http://pastebin.com/RVFk1D5k ... and in any case you can save one byte by using `<1` instead of `==0`.

Comment: @m.buettner :o I thought the equation I used have nothing to do with vectors (derived from simple algebra) but apparently they both yield the same equation. Math is wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

**Java, 149 characters**

```java
g=Math.atan2(100*(d-y),(a-x));h=Math.atan2(100*(e-y),(b-x));i=Math.atan2(100*(f-y),(c-x));k=Math.round(Math.abs(g-h)+Math.abs(h-i)+Math.abs(i-g))==6;
```

Horrible considering I have to write "Math." every time. This is the actual program:

```java
package mathPackage;
public class InTriangle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean k;
    double a=-1,b=0,c=1,d=0,e=1,f=0,x=0,y=0.4;
    double g,h,i;
    g=Math.atan2(100*(d-y),(a-x));
    h=Math.atan2(100*(e-y),(b-x));
    i=Math.atan2(100*(f-y),(c-x));
    k=Math.round(Math.abs(g-h)+Math.abs(h-i)+Math.abs(i-g))==6;
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println(g);
    System.out.println(h);
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.print(Math.abs(g-h)+Math.abs(h-i)+Math.abs(i-g));
}
}
```

where a is the x of point a,b is the x of point b, c for x of c, d is y of a, e is y of b, f is the y of c, and x and y are the x and y of the point. The boolean k determines whether it is true or not.

Comment: What are the `100*` for?

Answer (score 1):

### R, 23

Inspired by [MATLAB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32941/26904),

```
SDMTools::pnt.in.poly()
```

called like `SDMTools::pnt.in.poly(point,triangle)` where `point` is a length-2 vector and `triangle` is a 3x2 matrix of vertices. SDMTools is available on CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 38 characters

```
RegionMember[Polygon[#[[1]]],#[[2]]] &
```

Example:

```
d = {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .7}}, {.5, .6}};

RegionMember[Polygon[#[[1]]], #[[2]]] & @ d
```

(* True *)

Comment: It's standard to count spaces as characters, but presumably here you can remove them without anything breaking.

Comment: Also, you need to take input and produce output rather than using predefined variables. You can search up some Mathematica answers to see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 108 bytes

```c
i;f(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)float a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;{i=(e-=a)*(h-=b)>(f-=b)*(g-=a);i=(c-=a)*f>(d-=b)*e==i&i==g*d>h*c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVXLbiQ3DLznKwYLJOgxehbiQ3xgMP6SXLxjjz3AxgmCvS322x2KVF8C96kFSV0kq4rU9fR6vX583M@35Wn9tl7X5/Vlva2v69vx9v3vpx@H/@2ef94vy8vp8nR8WN5Ol2/Hx@U2Pg/L69g8x@k1T2@Py3MevFwu9z/ul8vrw/Pj28P1/Ovjr6f7@3L8@dvh8M@/9/cft@XL789/vn9Zb8upfSVwgfUQK0BhWQ@xZayWC2XwPKMmQLnqrp1zZb1zXhMhOh7Pn@ObMmreb80Ixn01Q88fG7fC9@atUIGsS@E3sT6usbHY5wHaVzT3iU8ilis0Esw/cYYkJ8K6pawViU18xmzsultBUzUaII0ZetHB1PuEA8kI3aHVlhNw5o3OLdPwRsR7BZBA04TvZEkLKrQMyLpx3RpxqaTOmqCGnYs89Ia2nz7IzBUbU1EVMWfp49cCRumzOoaKELesagOxfYUBwYt37ja1oA5o0yXckg3jLmkvdxIeCyAVLUNEpP0Chh8LCzpNr5pOv4SuVsp6V6h74cfEheY6vWTh5T0Fmm7ma4IlnXeYtBgjlvO1d6MpP7csBUTLoqYdfLeCUL@uhcI6teigVNzSljXy1NibbIyqY/6pbIQjwOcR3DfLBFlYnG4KBAvWZy0KPK0QxVTJlhFOqULbbTPozSrNLgi4ZmfT7CTSOIsN4UpC2jgZ1iMvr3I05C40ANcYYZcB7BgCViNws3VsMHlVJwE4vD/5QRfWPWCLxp3y97D7oBNxSujq7oHUTfoccTGmBmL0QWprwYzsQUf/T9aCPsraAbx4xxie2XdU49GtOa3FHPO0EuC@XZRIaoDYmFrDz8FI@i0cnlmS0eYQitmVWwCYl5RA9rup6zb1gh7IvKIfsWRy8iFkTDDIBuKYfT02kGYPUMy7XY@MCVgcdI9WHz4AsJmSjQ1CqJdlvAClddt8FSXKrpTEQpPumWIEsxoivY@N3gBx1oXDfExUTddiAu57JNqkXoh4/DwN4PN1QmAcFqFwccmhVMAoOjsGPG396@M/)

Takes three cross products and returns `1` if the sign of the `k̂` component doesn't change.