# Does the triangle contain the origin?

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

## Challenge description

On a Cartesian plane, a triangle can be described as a set of three points, each point being one of the triangle's vertices. For instance, coordinates `(2, 1), (6, 8), (-7, 3)` correspond to the following triangle:

[image: TRIANGLE #1]

As you can see, it does not contain the origin of the plane, i.e. the point `(0, 0)`, unlike the triangle `(-5, 3), (2, 7), (3, -8)`:

[image: TRIANGLE #2]

Your job is to write a program, that given exactly six integers describing coordinates of a triangle, determines whether or not it contains the origin of the Cartesian plane. The objective is to make your code as short as possible, since this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.

## Input

Six integers corresponding to three coordinates of a triangle, for example:

`1 4 -9 0 3 -4` -> `(1, 4), (-9, 0), (3, -4)`

You can also accept a list of integers, a list of two-tuples... - whatever is most convenient or makes your code shorter.

## Output

A truthy value if the triangle contains the origin (`1`, `True`), falsy value otherwise (`0`, `False`). You don't need to validate the input.

## Sample inputs / outputs

```
(18, -36), (36, 19), (-15, 9) -> True
(-23, 31), (-27, 40), (32, 22) -> False
(-40, -34), (35, 20), (47, 27) -> False
(0, 6), (-36, -42), (12, -34) -> True
(-24, 6), (36, 6), (-14, -25) -> True
```

*Triangle images courtesy of Wolfram Alpha*

Comment: Well-written challenge, but [we already have it](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32898/check-if-point-lies-inside-triangle).

Comment: Well, that's a shame... should've searched more thoroughly for duplicates. I'm just gonna leave it like this, worst-case scenario it will get deleted by mods.

Comment: Your challenge won't be deleted. It's closed, which disables answering it but keeps it visible.